# Cosa significa "cascare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Sto leggendo *La Locandiera* di Carlo Goldoni. La mia domanda è su questa frase pronunciata da Mirandolina, la locandiera, a proposito del Marchese di Forlipopoli, un nobile decaduto ospite della locanda:

> Che arsura! Non gliene cascano.

Il significato di ["arsura"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arsura/) nella frase precedente l'ho trovato nel vocabolario Treccani:

> ant., scherz. Estrema povertà, assoluta mancanza di denaro

Infatti, il Treccani riporta questa frase di Goldoni come esempio di questa accezione del vocabolo "arsura". Quello che non capisco bene è il senso di "cascare" in questo contesto.  Significa che non gli "cascano" i denari perché è senza un soldo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cercando su Google ho trovato questa frase:

> .. quando parla direttamente ai suoi interlocutori Mirandolina è sempre
>   educata e garbata, ed usa un linguaggio di impeccabile proprietà; ma
>   quando parla fra sé manifesta la sua vera natura, la sua sostanziale
>   volgarità di piccola borghese attaccata al denaro ( ad esempio nel
>   monologo della scena IX dell'atto I usa espressioni gergali tipo “Mi
>   piace l'arrosto e del fumo non so che farne”, mentre nel dialogo con
>   il marchese spiantato dice “***Che arsura! Non gliene cascano***”)..

Quindi direi che "non gliene cascano" si riferisca proprio ai soldi!

(!) aggiunta personale:  più che cascargli i soldi, credo sia cascar*le* i soldi. Molto probabilmente significa che il marchese non dà neanche qualche moneta a Mirandolina.

Comment: Questo [link](https://renatomastro1954.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/la-locandiera.pdf) conferma che questa espressione si riferisce proprio ai denari: "non perde certo per strada i denari per l’abbondanza".